# Is there a function to render html in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to conveniently render raw HTML in rstudio (e.g. in the 'plots' pane)? So far, I can view the raw HTML, but cannot render it (i.e. so it appears just as it would if opened in the browser)

E.g.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

html_object <- "https://stackoverflow.com/" %>% read_html

# This function displays the HTML (as text), but doesn't render it
render <- function(html_object) {
  tf <- tempfile()
  write_html(page_html, tf)
  viewer(tf)
}


render(html_object)
```

Is it possible to have a function render the HTML (as opposed to simply displaying HTML as text) ?

NOTE: I know it's possible to use `page_html %>% write_html("myfile.html")` and open the file with a browser

This is not a bad solution, but I am looking for it to render inside of Rstudio if possible, purely for convenience

Comment: Check out: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832288/rstudio-render-html-content-in-viewer-pane which is a question about the link given by @BenG

Comment: @BenG Here's what I tried: I updated to the most recent rstudio, I'm running an app at `http://localhost:3000/` and I ran `viewer("http://localhost:3000/", height = 500)` and it opens the 'Viewer' pane (looks promising) however it's completely blank

Comment: @CodeNoob Thanks for this, I am trying to render locally hosted content and still nothing, just a seemingly empty Viewer pane

Comment: @BenG by writing the file, it now displays some downloaded html, but as text (not rendered), I have updated the question accordingly. If you have any ideas please say